# Ubuntu 12.04 and now cannot get my vpn connection

Tags: 12.04, vpn, openvpn

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 ( 3 days ago ) and before that I had a very stable vpn connection even if 11.10 was less stable but now I cannot connect to my vpn account at home and at work either 
can somebody help please

Tina

Comment: Please provide excerpt from `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Hi Tina, you can use your terminal, and type: "cat /var/log/syslog > ~/Desktop/syslog" which will create a file on your desktop. Then open it using your Text editor and copy the text from the file to pastebin on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ so which Andrejs can have a look what might be wrong.

Comment: add syslog here also add that the connection showed as successful but cannot access any sites and pidgin is dead Thanks Andrejs for your help

Answer (score 1):

looks like this worked for me:
http://blog.403labs.com/post/22325731425/vpn-dns-resolving-woes-in-ubuntu-12-04
I can access sites now and my pidgin is good as well

Tina